# "fastboot set-active" command fails

Tags: fastboot

I'm trying to flash a custom ROM on my Xiaomi Mi A3. When I flashed the ROM using TWRP and rebooted my phone, it got stuck on fastboot mode, won't even boot to recovery.

I found a friend with a similar problem and he said that all he did was changing his current active slot, so I am now trying that. However, when I try to enter the command `fastboot set_active a` on my computer, it returns the usage message (the list of commands) and when I try the command `fastboot --set-active a`, it says unrecognized option.

I am using the platform-tools r29.0.5.

Answer (score 2):

The command shouldn't have any spaces. The correct command will be:

```
fastboot --set-active=a
```

**Or if you want to write it in short:**

`fastboot -aa` to set the active slot to A.

`fastboot -ab` to set the active slot to B.